# common between family of lines

Tags: calculus

suppose that there is a question like this :
[image]

i just want to make sure that i have understand  everything,maybe it is meant by this question that graph structure is  common,i mean  their graph is  straight line right?because let us take several value of $m$

$1.m=1$

$f(x)=1+(x+3)=x+4$

$2.m=2$

$f(x)=1+2*(x+3)=2*x+7$

$3. m=0$

$f(x)=1$

we see that for different $m$,we have different set of linear forms,so common is their graph right?others like $x$ intersection or $y$ intersection clearly is not  common,as well slopes,am i wrong?

Comment: Well, the "question" statement flat out tells you they are linear functions, so I think saying they are straight lines isn't saying much in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the point $\;(-3,1)\;$ is common
 to them all:

$$1=1+m(-3+3)\ldots$$

Comment: aa i see,because in this we would have  $f(-3)=1+m*(0)$

Comment: @dato you mean $f(-3)$ and not $f(x)$, of course...

Comment: yes sure i have changed

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** They have one common point, i think.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: For every $m$ point $(-3,1)$ is on the line $y=1+m(x+3)$

Comment: *what do you mean?* Think about the point-slope form of the equation, which happens to be $y-1 = m(x+3).$

Comment: i did not think about it